# 'Internal Server Error' for long audio files appeared after latest release | Model=latest_long | language=en-US

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Does someone faced with an Internal Server Error from Google S2T during last month?

- model: latest_long
- language: en-US
- audio duration > 30min (for shorter videos it works)

Inputs:

Endpoint: "us-central1-speech.googleapis.com:443"
Recognazer_pattern: "projects/anyclip.com:glowing-patrol-798/locations/us-central1/recognizers/_"

```
files {
  uri: "gs://anyclip-weavo-dev/2CviiI0BfNw-ptB56AN_/1707398899854_audio.flac"
}
config {
  features {
    enable_word_time_offsets: true
    enable_word_confidence: true
    enable_automatic_punctuation: true
  }
  auto_decoding_config {
  }
  model: "latest_long"
  language_codes: "en-US"
}
recognition_output_config {
  inline_response_config {
  }
}
```

```
error=OperationGoogleResponse.OperationError(code=13, message=An internal error occurred.)
```

[Problem appeared from 2024-01-30 17:27 (UTC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhTxS.png)